# Retrieving data from linking table (Many to Many). Laravel

Tags: many-to-many, laravel-5

Im trying to get data from my linking table sfees it is made up of student_id from students table and mfee_id from M_fees table.
My models are:

```
Student:
class student extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['first_name','middle_name','last_name','address','contact','dob','grade_id','status','scholorship','admission_year','passout_year'];

    public function grade() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Grade::class);
  }

  public function M_Fees() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\M_Fees');
  }
}
```

M_fees:

```
class M_fees extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = ['fee_type','amount'];

     public function Student()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student');
}
}
```

My table structure of sfees look like:
[image: Table sfees]

Now, how can i retrieve M_fees 'fee_type and amount) of particular student?
I have used following in my controller:

```
$student=Student::all()->whereLoose('id',$sid);
foreach ($student->M_fees as $M_fees) {
    echo $M_fees->pivot->fee_type;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It seems your pivot table is **sfees**.in which table **fee_type** & **amount** exists?

Comment: They exist in M_fees table

Comment: Did you try without using **pivot**. I mean **echo $M_fees->fee_type;** ?

Comment: Yes, it just keeps returning same errorexception: 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$M_fees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother try this.Sometimes you need to define the pivot table name.Hope will help.Let me know plz.

Student:

```
class student extends Model
{
    protected $table = "table_name";
    protected $fillable = ['first_name','middle_name','last_name','address','contact','dob','grade_id','status','scholorship','admission_year','passout_year'];

    public function grade() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Grade::class);
  }

  public function M_Fees() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\M_Fees','sfees');
  }
}
```

M_fees

```
class M_fees extends Model
{
     protected $table = "table_name";
     protected $fillable = ['fee_type','amount'];

     public function Student()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student','sfees');
}
}
```

Brother I think your looping has a problem.You have to loop through the student and for each student you have to fetch fee,amount.try this one.

Brother I think your looping has a problem.You have to loop through the student and for each student you have to fetch fee,amount.try this one.

```
foreach ($student as $single_student) {

foreach ($single_student->M_fees as $M_fees) {

    echo $M_fees->pivot->fee_type;
}
}
```

hope it will work.let me know

Comment: Have you checked your **$student** variable?I mean is there any value?

Comment: I am not sure whether your **$student** variable will have value or not. Is the query ok? or it should look like  **$student = Student::whereLoose('id',$sid)->get();**

Comment: [{"id":1,"first_name":"Manish","middle_name":"","last_name":"Maharjan","address":"KTM","dob":"2015-01-11","contact":"9801526987","scholorship":0.4,"admission_year":"2015-10-11","passout_year":"2010-10-11","grade_id":1,"status":"Active","created_at":"2016-06-18 09:54:51","updated_at":"2016-06-18 09:54:51"}]

Comment: You were right there was problem in my $students. I changed to  $student = Student::where('id',$sid)->first();
And it worked fine. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: If you have more than one entity/rows in $student variable then you can use the answer I just edit.You are most welcome @Anon :) :)